# In Extended Entity Relationship Diagrams, should you ever create subtypes if those subtypes do not have unique attributes?

Tags: database, inheritance, entity, diagram, erd

Basically, an employee can be a pilot, mechanic, or administrator.

My question focuses on the following business rules:

- The title, certificate, and specialization of the mechanics are recorded
- The mechanics are specialized in either engine (EN) maintenance, airframe (AF) maintenance or avionics (AV) maintenance.

No additional information is given in regards to the specializations. Would it be wrong if I did not make mechanic a supertype and its subtype to be its specialization? In terms of coding, I would not apply inheritance as the specializations do not have unique attributes or methods that make them distinct and I would rather use an enum or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the information is only the "type" then i see no problem with your suggested approach, though if that condition is liable to change (like adding specific information about the specialization) then i'd plan ahead and go for the other option so it's less of a pain change everything